# iOS: set font size of UILabel Programmatically

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm trying to set the font size of a UILabel. No matter what value I put though the text size doesn't seem to change. Here's the code I'm using.

```
[self setTitleLabel:[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0,0.0,428.0,50.0)]];
[[self contentView] addSubview:[self titleLabel]];
UIColor *titlebg = [UIColor clearColor];
[[self titleLabel] setBackgroundColor:titlebg];
[[self titleLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[self titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:36]];
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]` or `[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:36]`
i.e. `[[self titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]];`

Comment: setFont is deprecated in iOS 10.2

Answer (score 79):

Objective-C:

```
[label setFont: [label.font fontWithSize: sizeYouWant]];
```

Swift:

```
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(sizeYouWant)
```

just changes font size of a UILabel.

Comment: Apparently, setFont is deprecated, so `label.font =  // Whatever font.`

Comment: @FabricioPH how if I want to set `label.font = // whatever currently system's font` font ?

Comment: @ChenLiYong I'm not into iOS development anymore. Maybe Googling will display some relevant results about setting current system's font, or getting it. https://www.google.com/?#q=ios%20system%20font

Answer (score 26):

## Swift 3.0 / Swift 4.2 / Swift 5.0

```
labelName.font = labelName.font.withSize(15)
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for swift code:

```
var titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight",
                         size: 20.0)
```

Answer (score 7):

This code is perfectly working for me.

```
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,23, 350,22)];
  [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
```

Comment: Me too, [[self titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]]; did not and I don't know why

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3.0, you could use this code below:

```
let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:containerView.frame.width/2 - 35, y: 
    containerView.frame.height/2 + 10, width: 70, height: 20))
    textLabel.text = "Add Text"
    textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15.0) // set fontName and Size
    textLabel.textAlignment = .center
    containerView.addSubview(textLabel) // containerView is a UIView
```

Answer (score 3):

Its BECAUSE there is no font family with name `@"System"` hence `size:36` will also not work ...

Check the fonts available in xcode in attribute inspector and try

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8

```
  static NSString *_myCustomFontName;

 + (NSString *)myCustomFontName:(NSString*)fontName
  {
 if ( !_myCustomFontName )
  {
   NSArray *arr = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontName];
    // I know I only have one font in this family
    if ( [arr count] > 0 )
       _myCustomFontName = arr[0];
  }

 return _myCustomFontName;

 }
```

Comment: Might be also problem of your font target membership.