# how to show color text with large font on score label when user press correct answer during game in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a simple game,in which randomly math question display and user is ask to answer to this question.If user press correct answer then scoreLabel which display score should update with some animation view and if user answer wrong then another label should display with horizoentaly animation view to inform user that answer is wrong.
Please help me about this.

Comment: press correct answer how u handle that one?

Comment: we compare our answer with formula calculated answer,if answer match then we will update our label that is score but with some animation

Comment: You used uibutton for user press right?

Comment: while pressing the right answer set your font and size.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575626/ios-set-font-size-of-uilabel-programmatically

Comment: Bro,actually i want to set red color to scoreLabel and font size of  30 only for 4 second.After this scoreLabel should look like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something I have incorporated into one of my games. It wasn't for correct and incorrect answer but you can start with it.

I simply have to PNG images for each button. You would have three, the correct, the incorrect, and the neutral. I simply designed them different that's all, so when I click on it, it changes to another color. If that's similar to your issue than the coding would look something like this.

I'm using my Play Button as example for you

IN MY (CONFIGURATIONS.H):

```
/********************** BUTTON PLAY         **********************/

static NSString *kPlayBtnName               = @"btnPlay";

static NSString *kImgPlayBtn                = @"play";

static NSString *kImgPlayPressBtn           = @"play_press";

//***********************************************************//
```

IN MY (GAME OBJECTS.M):

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)btnPlay{

    SKSpriteNode *btnPlay = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:kImgPlayBtn];

    btnPlay.name = kPlayBtnName;

    btnPlay.zPosition = 1;

    return btnPlay;
}
```